# Where can I find GRASS i.ortho.rectify?

Tags: grass-gis, orthorectification

I currently have several versions of GRASS GIS installed on PC with Windows 7 (6.4.3, 6.4.4, 7.0.4, and 7.1). I cannot find the i.ortho.rectify module. It appears to be missing. I have searched and browsed through all of the modules. Any ideas about what might be wrong?

Comment: Which version doesn't have i.ortho.rectify? All? Did you try to type "i.ortoh.rectify" at the GRASS command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_7_2/imagery/i.ortho.photo/README?rev=69510 :

```
STATUS:
        The i.ortho.photo suite of modules has been temporarily disabled
        from GRASS 7 as they are heavily dependent on the text-based
        Vask libary and interactive XDRIVER monitors, both of which
        have been removed. As the modules are rewritten to run in non-
        interactive mode or with a wxPython frontend, they will be
        added back into GRASS 7. This work will be undertaken in the
        trunk SVN.
```

i.ortho.rectify is part of i.ortho.photo, so you have to wait until that is re-implemented.

Comment: It is available in GRASS GIS 6 (the latest 6.4.6 was released at FOSS4G 2016), but it will not be usable on Windows. Please use either Linux or Mac OSX for the i.ortho.photo suite of modules. We hope to provide a portable version for GRASS GIS 7 one day (volunteers or sponsors welcome)